# Sticky Header within a Scrollable Container

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

There is a bunch of questions about the sticky elements in DOM and wide range of libraries to take care of it, for example:

jquery.pin, sticky-kit and many more

but the problem with all of them is that they only work with the whole body being scrolled, and with restriction that the parent container must have default overflow setting.

[image]

The example page of [Sticky-kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) shows perfectly what I need. Just that in their case their case they actually use an `iframe`. In mine, it's a Div with `overflow: auto` (it's an app with flexbox layout with fixed header, footer and left menu, while the main content scrolls).

So I want the red box 'stick me' to stay there when I scroll the gray box. The green elements have no scroll and they never move. My requirements:

- The body doesn't scroll
- No iframes
- I'd prefer no timeout running every 50ms

So far I can see several solutions:

- position:fixed on the red box, and a) duplicate its content (not an option) b) dynamically adjust the margin/padding of the gray container to force elements to stay below the red box (perfect but the box may expand, and its not easy to monitor its height and readjust the margin). Like this one, but the header height might change: http://jsfiddle.net/KTgrS/
- position: absolute on the red box, and readjust it on the scroll event of the gray box. Possible, but again the scroll doesn't provide the scroll 'delta', and getting it is kind of sketchy.

Any other ideas or way to make the ones above feasible for actual production use? Support for the recent browsers is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Correct answer

To easily accomplish this:

```
$('.greybox').on('scroll',function(event){
  $('.redbox').css({top: $(this).scrollTop()});
});
```

### Original answer:

it's easier to put both red and grey in a container at the same level.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="redbox"></div>
  <div class="greybox"></div>
</div>
```

for styling:

```
.container
{
  position: relative;
  width: ...px;
  height: ...px;
}
.redbox
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
.greybox
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top:  20px; // height of the redbox
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

now redbox looks like it's sticky, but you don't need any JS or sticky stuff, at all :-)

Comment: well, i cannot fix the size of neither grey or red box. But in general such solution is possible and doesnt need the position abosulute neither :) 
But there are 2 issues with that approach, 1) The red box is a part of different controls that are dynamically inserted in the greybox, I would need to extract it outside, and this is neither nice or compatibile with data binding 2) The scroll starts below the red box and it won't look good, very oldschool. Red box must stay within the grey one.

Comment: ah ok, yeah, that does indeed change it all. easiest thing to do then is set the redbox to position absolute within the greybox, with it's `top` set to   `greybox.scrollTop` on scroll. easiest solution :-)

Comment: haha, where was my mind, I was sure scrollTop works only with the window, but I have not checked that. It is indeed available for each DOM element, great, I'll bind it like this, and only take care of CPU use and fluency. Make it an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: yeah i'll update my answer in a bit. Love it when the solution is just not thought of yet :-)

Comment: I just wonder why none of the libraries, and I have checked a bunch, has not included such case, they mostly work in similar way, just bound to the window scope

Comment: it's probably because people need to sticky someone to the top of the screen. So if you would scroll your whole screen, the red box would sticky to the top of your screen. I myself would just implement it with a data attribute to say what it should sticky against (parent, body or selector)